# Identify Treeview Row id based on value in any column

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I am making a Tkinter GUI with Treeview by inserting a dataframe. I would like now to identify treeview rowid's based on values in a column. I cannot use right, left, double click etc. 'event' in this case due to nature of input. Is there any way to get desired output. Thanks in advance for support.

Comment: Go through the rows and compare the value in required column with the expected value, if match returns the rowid. Note that it may return more than one rowid.

Comment: @acw1668 this is where I am struggling. Here is my code line "marked_rows_index = [self.trv.identify_row() for rows in self.trv.get_children() if self.trv.item(rows, 'tags')[0]=='marked']". Here 'tags' is column and I am looking for value 'marked' in column. However, I am not able to figure out what argument shall I pass into 'identify_row()'.

Comment: It may be like `marked_rows_index = [row for row in self.trv.get_children() if self.trv.set(row, 'tags') == 'marked']`.

Comment: @acw1668, thanks. It was pretty simple. I made it complicated :).